# Для чего нужны файлы *.h?

Tags: windows, c++, visual-studio

Начинаю изучать Visual С++ (2010), раньше пользовался паскалем, поэтому:

1. не совсем понимаю, для чего нужны заголовочные файлы;
2. что конкретно в них прописывается (должно прописываться).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если говорить применительно паскаля/делфи, то хедер - это фактически iterface секция, тогда `*.с`, `*.cpp` - это implementation часть. Грубо, конечно, но на первое время достаточно.

Comment: А более точно где то можно об этом почитать. А то получается странно: беру программы из примеров, и даже в одном источнике, в разных проектах, скажем директива #include пишется и в .сpp и в .h файлах. Как это понять? И кстати interface/implementation - структура модуля/библиотеки. Получается что все что я пишу на С++ сплошной модуль?

Comment: Директива include фактически подставляет содержимое файла. Но если глянуть на него внутрь, то там обычно стоит такая штука

    #ifndef XXXXXXX
    #define XXXXXXX
    //код
    #endif

и эта штука не дает включать дважды один файл. И что бы не запоминать, где включили, а где нет - просто берут и включают в двух местах. 

>И кстати interface/implementation - структура модуля/библиотеки. Получается что все что я пишу на С++ сплошной модуль?

Нет конечно. Я же написал "грубо". А вот где почитать об этом всем - да в любой нормальной книжке.

Comment: Эта директива выключает компиляцию блока, заключенного в скобки `#ifndef #endif`, а в отдельном файле она или нет - никакой разницы.

Comment: но есть особая разновидность этой директивы, когда она обрамляет весь файл и называется http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Не то что бы я абсолютно разобрался, но основную суть как мне кажется уловил. Всем огромное спасибо. 
KoVadim`у особая благодарность за последнюю ссылку.

Comment: С точки зрения синтаксиса, никакого отдельной разновидности `#ifdef/#ifndef` в данном случае не применяется.

Comment: Это логическая разновидность. Такая, что некоторые умные компиляторы умеют видеть ее и обрабатывать в ускоренном режиме.

Comment: Сомневаюсь. Вы не путаете с прагмой?

Comment: Нет конечно. Почитайте здесь http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Once_002dOnly-Headers.html 
Опять же повторюсь - разновидность логическая.

Answer (score 10):

Если константы, прототипы функций, макросы, объявления структур и тому подобная информация используется (является общей) в нескольких файлах с кодом программ, то ее помещают в .h файл, который включается в .c файлы (или другие .h) директивой препроцессора #include. Т.о. общие данные не дублируются. Они изменяются в одном месте и эти изменения согласованно включаются в коды программ.